# How to show no result found in Ajax Laravel search?

Tags: ajax, laravel, search, livesearch

I want to show 'No Results Found' in the Laravel Ajax search. In my case, if there is no record, it shows a blank screen. So I want to change it to "No results found." Can someone help me?

**View**

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 25px;">
     <div class="col-md-8" >
          <h2 id="dynamic-row"></h2>
     </div>
</div>    
<script>
    $('body').on('click' ,'#search' , function(){
        var from = $('#from').val();
        var to = $('#to').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route("fare.search") }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                '_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                from : from,
                to: to,
            },
            success: function(res){
                var tableRow = '';
                $('#dynamic-row').html('');
                $.each(res , function(index,value){
                    tableRow = '<h2>RS &nbsp;'+value.fare+'/-</h2>';                   
                    $('#dynamic-row').append(tableRow);
                    //$('#dynamic-row').css('font-weight', 'bold');
                    
                })
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply return the 404 on "No result found" in Controller.

```
return response()->json('No Result Found', 404);
```

And add the error function in ajax call:

```js
$('body').on('click' ,'#search' , function(){
        var from = $('#from').val();
        var to = $('#to').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route("fare.search") }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                '_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                from : from,
                to: to,
            },
            success: function(res){
                var tableRow = '';
                $('#dynamic-row').html('');
                $.each(res , function(index,value){
                    tableRow = '<h2>RS &nbsp;'+value.fare+'/-</h2>';                   
                    $('#dynamic-row').append(tableRow);
                    //$('#dynamic-row').css('font-weight', 'bold');
                    
                })
            },
            error: function(res){
              console.log(res);
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. This is my controller.`public function fareSearch(Request $request){
        $from = $request->from;
        $to = $request->to;
        $fares = fare::where('from', '=' , "$from")->where('to', '=' , "$to")->get();
        if($fares){
            return json_encode($fares);
        }else{
            return response()->json('No Result Found', 404);   
        }
        
    }`

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. Now you will be able to catch 404 in the error function, see my answer here console.log(res) prints "No Result Found" in the console, Do it whatever you want append it in a table, etc.